# How to git commit and push?

Tags: git, sublimemerge

I must be missing something, almost always when I'm about to push my commit I'll get blocked because somebody else pushed a commit just before me and my changes (my commit) is not based on the tip of the remote any more.

At this situation I'll clone the repo again (in another folder) and manually change every file again, commit and hope nobody pushed just before me again. Sometimes it happens though and so I'll clone the repo in another folder a second time and same history repeats.

While observing commit history, with my approach I see a clean line, which I like.

I noticed other developers in the project are making a merge commit frequently after their own commits. I guess that's because they are facing the same situation as me (somebody else pushed before and changes are not based on tip anymore) but they are handling the situation in a different way (using a merge commit).

The problem is that these merge commits (at least the way they are being done) do not introduce anything, they just repeat the changes from previous commit because it seems developer did not issued a pull before push. In other words I'll say, commit history line is dirty.

I guess the merge commit approach is faster to handle than clone repo again and modify every single file again. But commit history line is dirty.

Project use just one branch, the master. And is hosted in a shared folder in local network.

I use to do git from command line but these days I'm using https://www.sublimemerge.com almost all the time.

How can I improve my commit/push workflow? Should I use other tools?

Comment: Whenever you can't push you _clone the repo again?_ If you don't like merge commits, why not rebase?

Comment: rebasing ot merging _definitely_ don't call for cloning the repo again! :-O That is such an overkill.

Comment: well... I think you should learn how to use _branches_ and how to do basic rebasing/merging. As a side note, cloning and then moving over the files is _not_ a correct way to do it. If there are changes in those files that were introduced by other developers in the branch after you started your own branch, you are reverting (unwillingly/unknowingly) those changes. Proper rebasing/merging avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

For start, it would be better if you did your development on a different branch. Even if your other developers insist on doing it this way, it doesn't prevent you from branching.

1. Create a new branch.
2. Do your work, committing to this branch as necessary.
3. Switch to master
4. Pull down new changes.
5. Merge your branch into master
6. Push the changes.

Alternatively, if you really insist on not using branches and you don't like these merge commits, you could do a rebase.

Comment: I'm foreseeing I'll get blocked at step 5. Merge your branch into master. And since  I'm on my own branch for many commits it probably will be even harder to handle. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @KcFnMi: You shouldn't. I suppose if your team is bad about communicating, there's a chance you'll face merge conflicts.

Comment: If you really want to avoid merge commits entirely, you could rebase your branch on top of master, though that can be tricky with public branches.

Comment: Oh, I think I got the idea. The interface between each branch must be very clear. Let's say projcet have three components/folders then we make a branch for each?

Answer (score 1):

> At this situation I'll clone the repo again (in another folder) and manually change everyfile again,

This is quite tedious.

Instead, do this:

```
git fetch
git rebase -i origin/master
```

This will automatically merge all of the changes that other folks make. In cases where the changes conflict with yours, it'll let you resolve those conflicts.

Then finally

```
git push
```

Comment: You can just `git pull -r` instead.

Comment: If I'm working in `my-branch`, will that rebase on top of `origin/master` or `origin/my-branch`? The former is what I want.

Comment: If you're working on a branch the remote shouldn't be ahead of local so you wouldn't need to pull at all. In that case I'd suggest pulling on master _then_ rebasing the branch on your local master; otherwise you leave master behind origin/master which could be confusing later on.

Comment: The commands in my answer achieve that. Without having to switch to master and then back to my branch.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise. If you're on master pull -r is shorter, though, and if you're not then doing this will leave local master behind origin/master.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not used to working on master. I misunderstood the premise.